# C# - How do you use integers in c# to indentify the the limit to select from the table from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, select

Current im trying to use this im my code to try and read specific data between two different rows: example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM chat 
 LIMIT 1, 20
```

In my c# code ive current got:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from chat LIMIT " + cCfirst + "'" + cClast + "'";
```

Which isnt working in my code as the data reader isn't finding anything? 
 how can i fix this?

Comment: did you missed a comma? `+ cCfirst + "," + cClast +`

Comment: Don't compose SQL string dynamically. Learn about parameterized SQL in C#, and use it everywhere in your projects. You'll be happy that you did.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It still didn't work D: <br>             con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from chat LIMIT " + cCfirst + "," + cClast + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not *constructing* string from chunks which is prone to errors

```
// wrong technique, do not do it: 
//   1. Can you see that "," is omitted?
//   2. Can you see that both "'" are at least redundant?  
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from chat LIMIT " + cCfirst + "'" + cClast + "'";
```

but *formatting* e.g. with a help of *string interpolation* (C# 6.0+):

```
cmd.CommandText = 
  $@"SELECT * 
       FROM chat 
      LIMIT {cCfirst}, {cClast}";
```

Or in case of C# 5.0-

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
  @"SELECT * 
      FROM chat 
     LIMIT {0}, {1}", 
   cCfirst, cClast);
```

Make SQL being *readable*. Open SQL editor, debug the query, copy the query debugged into C# code, turn values into `{...}` placeholders (e.g. `1` -> `{cCfirst}`; `20` -> `{cClast}`).

Then use the code:

```
 using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(YourCOnnectionString)) {
   con.Open();

   using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
     cmd.Connection = con;

     cmd.CommandText =
       $@"SELECT * 
            FROM chat 
           LIMIT {cCfirst}, {cClast}";

     using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
       while (reader.Read()) {
         //TODO: put relevant code here
       }
     }
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Appreciate this a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

The following illustrates the LIMIT clause syntax with two arguments:

```
SELECT 
column1,column2,...
FROM
table
LIMIT offset , count;
```

In your C# code it seems you are missing comma between offset and count.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from chat LIMIT " + cCfirst + "," + cClast;
```

Comment: Legend! Thank, mate

Comment: You are welcome buddy... mark the answer right if it works well.